How to check if some other package is able to post notifications on Android 10~12?
My app enhances the notification experience of the default SMS app, it shows notification when there is incoming SMS message.
I need user to disable the notification of the default SMS app, otherwise there will be double notifications. I want to show a warning if it's not disabled, the problem is how to check it? On Android 13+ there is
context.packageManager.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS, defSmsPkg)

But the POST_NOTIFICATIONS isn't available for lower version, how to do that on Android 10~12?
Please notice that I don't want to introduce new permissions.

Note that holding POST_NOTIFICATIONS as a permission does not mean that an app has the ability to post notifications. The user could disable notifications for the other app in other ways in the Settings app. IOW, your code will generate false positives for "the app can post notifications". I do not recall a way for your app to know reliably whether some other app can post notifications, including on those older Android versions.

Understood, I don't need it to be 100% accurate, only want it to be able to check whether the user has turned off that global notification switch in system settings.
